# WordPress parabola theme colour scheme changes on single page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, color-scheme

Long story short, I have been using the theme parabola on my website, I love the theme and have been using the default colour scheme as I find I like that one the best however I have a static page for a film I have begun shooting that has a dark scifi horror theme about it and I would like to portray that on the page. Problem is I don't want to change the colour scheme on the whole website but I don't know how to call a specific one that they have to the single page.

Any suggestions? Cheers.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it isn't a specific programming question. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit.

Comment: Good point. Apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an ideal solution, but it should work.

You can add some some CSS to your post using the text editor (not the visual editor), like this:

```
<style>
body.postid-745 { background: red; }
</style>
```

A possible better solution would be using a custom CSS plugin (this one may work: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/) or manually adding a CSS stylesheet. I would avoid editing any of the theme's code since it would likely be overwritten when updating.

Comment: Thank you this suited my needs perfectly without needing to get down and messy with the established css :-)